# How to upload file in native app using sendkeys in appium

Tags: appium-ios

I am trying to upload file by adding

```
driver.findElementsByXpath("").sendkeys("filepath");
```

but that is not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I formatted the code in your question so it is easier to read. However, your question is missing some crucial information. PLease take a look at the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to repeat that trick from web in native mobile app: simply because it doesn't work that easy here.
You have to do it step by step, e.g. click button to open gallery, find image in gallery and click it, etc.
On the other hand, there is a `push_file` end point in Appium to put file on device: https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/files/push-file/

There is a nice blog post with code sample available [here](https://appiumpro.com/editions/2):

```java
File assetDir = new File(classpathRoot, "../assets");
File img = new File(assetDir.getCanonicalPath(), "cloudgrey.png");
driver.pushFile(ANDROID_PHOTO_PATH + "/" + img.getName(), img);

// navigate to photo selection in your app, open gallery and click the recently uploaded image
```

Comment: i have same issue. i don't know where to put file in device? what should be destination path? can you guide.

Comment: @UttamPanara Did you find solution for this?

Comment: Check this blog post https://appiumpro.com/editions/2 and mark answer up if it makes sense for you